# Очередь, функция возвращение головы без удаления

Tags: c, очередь

Есть структура, которая описывает очередь и есть функции для работы с ней.

```
typedef struct node_t {
    /* Структура описывает элемент очереди*/
    int value;
    struct node_t* next;
}  TNode;

typedef struct list_t {
    /* Структура описывает очередь */
    TNode* head;
    TNode* tail;
}  TList;

TList* pushBack(TList* list, int value) {
    /* Добавляет элемент в хвост очереди */
    TNode* node = (TNode*) malloc(sizeof(TNode));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;

    if (list->head && list->tail) {
        list->tail->next = node;
        list->tail = node;
    } else {
        list->head = list->tail = node;
    }

    return list;
}

int pop(TList* list) {
    /* Возвращает голову очереди, УДАЛЯЯ ее*/
    TNode* node = list->head;
    list->head = node->next;
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->tail = NULL;
    }
    int value = node->value;

    return value;
}
```

Необходимо создать и заполнить две очереди (элементы упорядочены по возрастанию), и соединить их в третий список, который тоже упорячен по возрастанию. 
Очевидно, код для этого:

```
int main() {
    TList queue1 = {NULL, NULL}; 
    TList queue2 = {NULL, NULL}; 

    printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int value;
        scanf("%i", &value);
        pushBack(&queue1, value);
    }

    printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int value;
        scanf("%i", &value);
        pushBack(&queue2, value);
    }

    TList result = {NULL, NULL};
    for( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //слияние и сортировка.

        if( show(queue1) <  show(queue2)){
            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue1));
        }
        else{
            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue2));
        }
     }

    while (!isEmpty(&result)) {
        printf("%d ", pop(&result));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Но для этого нужно описать некую функцию show(), которая возвращала бы голову очереди без его удаления. Я написал ее так.

```
int show(TList list) {
    /* Возвращает голову, НЕ УДАЛЯЯ ее*/
    TNode* node = list.head;
    int value = node-> value; /* здесь программа падает с SIGSEG*/

    return value;
}
```

Но программа падает с ошибкой сегментации. Хотя, код идентичен тому же pop, только без удаления.
В чем причина? Как исправить? Как правильно?

Comment: Только pop правильно сделан в отличие от show и берет указатель на список а не копию этого списка которая разрушается после вызова

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже нашел. Вот функция:

```
int show(TList list) {
    /* Возвращает голову, НЕ УДАЛЯЯ ее*/
    TNode* node = list.head;
    if (list.head == NULL) {
        list.tail = NULL;
    }
    int value = node->value;

    return value;
}
```

Вот мейн:

```
int main() {
    TList queue1 = {NULL, NULL}; //cоздание двух очередей и инициализация их хвоста и головы NULL
    TList queue2 = {NULL, NULL}; //

    printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int value;
        scanf("%i", &value);
        pushBack(&queue1, value);
    }

    printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int value;
        scanf("%i", &value);
        pushBack(&queue2, value);
    }

    TList result = {NULL, NULL};
    for( i = 0; !isEmpty(&queue1) || !isEmpty(&queue2); i++){
        //слияние и сортировка

        //"пишем" из исходных массивов в результирующий. Пишет - значит удаляем (pop) из исходящего и добавляем (pushBack) в результирующий
        if ( !isEmpty(&queue1) && isEmpty(&queue2) ){
            //если первый непустой а пустой, пишем из первого
            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue1));
        }
        else if (isEmpty(&queue1) && !isEmpty(&queue2)){
            //если второй  непустой а первый пустой, пишем из второго

            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue2));
        }
        else if( show(queue1) <  show(queue2)){
            //если оба не пустых, сравниваем вершины. У кого вершина меньше, того и добавляем
            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue1));
        }
        else{
            pushBack(&result, pop(&queue2));
        }
     }

    //печать списка
    while (!isEmpty(&result)) {
        printf("%d ", pop(&result));
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего хотел бы указать на непоследовательность в наименовании методов. Как известно для контейнера очередь элементы вставляются в конец очереди, а извлекаются из начала очереди. То есть эта структура с поведением FIFO (first input, first output).

Поэтому если вы назвали один из методов `pushBack` , то было бы логично противоположный метод назвать `popFront`. Обычно, так как это известно для очередей, то методы называют просто `push` и `pop` без использования дополнительных слов `back` и `front`.

Имя `show` обычно используется для обозначения метода, который выводит в поток все элементы контейнера. Метод, который лишь возвращает значение в начале очереди, обычно называется `peak`.

Кроме того ваш метод `show` имеет неопределенное поведение, так как в общем случае член класса `head` может быть равным `NULL`.
Поэтому предложение

```
int value = node->value;
```

некорректное.

Также нет никакой необходимости устанавливать член класса `tail` в `NULL`, так как этот метод не должен менять состояние контейнера.

Кроме того вы нарушаете общий интерфейс, когда другие методы объявляют первым параметром указатель на список.

```
int show(TList list) {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^ 
    /* Возвращает голову, НЕ УДАЛЯЯ ее*/
    TNode* node = list.head;
    if (list.head == NULL) {
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - ???
        list.tail = NULL;
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - ???
    }
    int value = node->value;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - ???

    return value;
}
```

Метод `pop` также имеет неопределенное поведение, так как в общем случае член класса `head` может быть равен `NULL`, а потому обращения `node->next` и `node->value` некорректные

```
int pop(TList* list) {
    /* Возвращает голову очереди, УДАЛЯЯ ее*/
    TNode* node = list->head;
    list->head = node->next;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - ??? 
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->tail = NULL;
    }
    int value = node->value;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - ??? 

    return value;
}
```

Также у вас имеется опечатка. Вы оба раза просите ввести элементы первого списка

```
printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
//                            ^^^^^ 
//...
printf("Enter the elements of first queue(5):");
//                            ^^^^^
```

Очевидно, что для второго ввода вы имели в виду

```
printf("Enter the elements of second queue(5):");
//                            ^^^^^^
```

Целесообразно объединение списков вынести в отдельную функцию.

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа с отдельно написанной функцией конкатенации списков.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_t 
{
    /* Структура описывает элемент очереди*/
    int value;
    struct node_t* next;
}  TNode;

typedef struct list_t 
{
    /* Структура описывает очередь */
    TNode* head;
    TNode* tail;
}  TList;

int isEmpty( TList *list )
{
    return list->head == NULL;
}

TList * push( TList *list, int value ) 
{
    /* Добавляет элемент в хвост очереди */
    TNode *node = ( TNode * ) malloc( sizeof( TNode ) );

    node->value = value;
    node->next  = NULL;

    if ( list->tail ) 
    {
        list->tail->next = node;
    } 
    else 
    {
        list->head = node;
    }

    list->tail = node;

    return list;
}


int pop( TList *list ) 
{
    /* Возвращает голову очереди, УДАЛЯЯ ее */
    int value = 0;

    if ( list->head )
    {
        value = list->head->value;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        if ( !list->head ) list->tail = NULL;
    }

    return value;
}

int peak( TList *list )
{
    return list->head ? list->head->value : 0;
}

TList concat( TList *list1, TList *list2 )
{
    TList result = { NULL, NULL };

    while ( !isEmpty( list1 ) && !isEmpty( list2 ) )
    {
        if ( peak( list2 ) < peak( list1 ) )
        {
            push( &result, pop( list2 ) );
        }
        else
        {
            push( &result, pop( list1 ) );
        }
    }

    while ( !isEmpty( list1 ) ) push( &result, pop( list1 ) );
    while ( !isEmpty( list2 ) ) push( &result, pop( list2 ) );

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    TList queue1 = { NULL, NULL };
    TList queue2 = { NULL, NULL };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) push( &queue1, 2 * i );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) push( &queue2, 2 * i + 1 );

    TList result = concat( &queue1, &queue2 );

    while ( !isEmpty( &result ) ) printf( "%d ", pop( &result ) );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```